# Save excel file with Worksheet.SaveAs to any/selected directory

Tags: c#, excel, savefiledialog, save-as

I have figured out how to save my excel file to the specified directory, but when the `SaveFileDialog` box opens I would like to be able to save anywhere I want. How can I do this?

```
private void btnExcellExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount == 0))
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                return;
            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", RestoreDirectory = true, InitialDirectory = HelpMeClass.GetExcelDirectory
        })
            {
                sfd.FileName = HelpMeClass.SearchString;
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    progressBar1.Show();
                    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                    progressBar1.Value = 0;
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Oops! Nothing to export!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }
```

BackgroundWorker:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

        excel.Visible = true;
        int index = 0;

        int process = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        int process1 = dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
        int process2 = dataGridView3.Rows.Count;



        ws.get_Range("A1", "C1").Merge(); // Merge columns for header
        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Keyword: " + HelpMeClass.SearchString;
        ws.Cells[1, 1].Font.Bold = true; // Bold font in header


        if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process);

                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    ws.Cells[index + 1, 1] = cell.Value;
                }
            }

            index = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process1);

                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    ws.Cells[index + 1, 2] = cell.Value;
                }
            }

            index = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process2);

                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    ws.Cells[index + 1, 3] = cell.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        ws.Columns.AutoFit();



        try
        {
            ws.SaveAs(Path.Combine(HelpMeClass.GetExcelDirectory, HelpMeClass.SearchString), XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ooops! I can`t access the file. Make sure the excel file is closed and try again. " + ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            return;
        }

        //excel.Quit();

    }
```

The `InitialDirectory` gets the path string of `public string GetExcelDirectory { get; } = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Desktop\";` I would like to have a chance to save the file anywhere I want instead.

Also in `SaveAs` statement, I`m combining this path with a filename.

Comment: Have you searched for an answer before posting? see https://stackoverflow.com/q/33411063/4961700 and the answers given...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this approach instead. I have saved the selected path using `Path.GetFirectoryName(sfd.FileName);`. Then is a SaveAs I passed that directory and combined with a file name. This works perfectly.

```
private void btnExcellExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount == 0))
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                return;
            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", RestoreDirectory = true, InitialDirectory = HelpMeClass.ExcelSaveDirectory
            })
            {

                sfd.FileName = HelpMeClass.SearchString;

                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    HelpMeClass.ExcelSaveDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(sfd.FileName);
                    progressBar1.Show();
                    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                    progressBar1.Value = 0;
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Oops! Nothing to export!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }



private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

        excel.Visible = true;
        int index = 0;

        int process = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        int process1 = dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
        int process2 = dataGridView3.Rows.Count;



        ws.get_Range("A1", "C1").Merge(); // Merge columns for header
        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Keyword: " + HelpMeClass.SearchString;
        ws.Cells[1, 1].Font.Bold = true; // Bold font in header


        if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process);

                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    ws.Cells[index + 1, 1] = cell.Value;
                }
            }

            index = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process1);

                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    ws.Cells[index + 1, 2] = cell.Value;
                }
            }

            index = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process2);

                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    ws.Cells[index + 1, 3] = cell.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        ws.Columns.AutoFit();



        try
        {
            ws.SaveAs(Path.Combine(HelpMeClass.ExcelSaveDirectory, HelpMeClass.SearchString), XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ooops! I can`t access the file. Make sure the excel file is closed and try again. " + ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            return;
        }

        //excel.Quit();

    }
```