# Allow user to choose the save file path for "print PDF"

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, save-as

I have a commandbutton on the Excel file that allows the user to automate the "Print PDF" feature with a click. The issue being, at the moment I can only save the file to the specified location within the code. I want to let the user choose their save directory similar to the actual saving feature.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub PrintPDF_Button_Click()

    Dim mySheets As Variant, sh

    mySheets = Array("COVER", "SCOPE", "SUMMARY", "Updated Hours EST", "RATES")

    Sheets(mySheets).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\sravi\test" & _
        ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, openafterpublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select folder for save location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411063/select-folder-for-save-location)

Comment: I am going to roll back your question to the previous state, because your edit was due to the other answer and it somewhat invalidates your accepted answer. Just to let you know why I am doing it.

Comment: understood and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method you can use is the `Application.FileDialog()` method. You will be able to set a default save location and even a default file name if you'd like.

```
Dim fileSave As FileDialog
Set fileSave = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fileSave
    ' Your default save location here
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\sravi\*.pdf"

    If .Show = -1 Then

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, openafterpublish:=True

    End If
End With
```

## Breaking it down

You can set the default save path using the `.InitialFileName` property. If you have a default file name, you can use that. Otherwise, set the default file type using `*.pdf`

```
.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\sravi\*.pdf"
```

The following line serves two purposes:

1. Shows the dialog box with `.Show`
2. Ensures that the user accepted a save location with `.Show = -1`

```
If .Show = -1 Then
```

Then finally, you would return your file path to the method you're using with this line:

```
Filename:=.SelectedItems(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` method. Use the returned value as the `Filename` attribute, but check to make sure it is not `False` before saving.